# SQL- how to count duplicates with conditions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like below:

```
ID   Doc ID      Names
XX    97...      Name1
XY    97...      Name 2
XZ    98...      Name 1
...
```

Now I want to find ALL the duplicates that exist for a particular name, but only any of the duplicates within the names contains a Doc Id beginning with 97.
A simple duplicate query for SQL isn't helping, please help.

[expected input & output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTBur.png)

Comment: Can you provide an example of input with associated expected output? (No "...")

Comment: Yes, something like this:

Comment: I've edited the answer to provide an image. Notice that we don't select Amelia, because she doesnt have a doc ID beginning with 97.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Table1.*, Query1.CountOfDocID
FROM (SELECT Names, Count(DocID) AS CountOfDocID FROM Table1 GROUP BY Names) AS Query1 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Query1.Names = Table1.Names
WHERE CountOfDocID>1 AND Table1.Names IN (SELECT Names FROM Table1 WHERE DocID LIKE "97*");
```

In response to your comment question, put function from [Allen Browne](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html)  site into a general module. Call the function in query or textbox

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Names, Query1.[CountOfDocID], 
ConcatRelated("DocID","Table1","Names='" & [Table1]![Names] & "'") AS Docs
FROM (SELECT Names, Count(DocID) AS CountOfDocID FROM Table1 GROUP BY Names)  AS Query1 
INNER JOIN Table1 ON Query1.Names = Table1.Names
WHERE [CountOfDocID]>1 AND Table1.Names In (SELECT Names FROM Table1 WHERE DocID LIKE "97*");
```

Comment: Thank you! If I were to concatenate say, Doc ID of record 1 and record 2 together, where would I put it? Putting it after select doesn't help.

Comment: See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT First(tblEmployee.[empid]) AS [tblEmployee.EmployeeID], Count([tblEmployee.empid]) AS NumberOfDups
FROM tblEmployee
GROUP BY tblEmployee.[empid]
HAVING (((Count(tblEmployee.[empid]))>1));
```

https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Duplicates-Easily-in-Microsoft-Access